# Binary operation cannot be applied when using generics for arithmetic

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to implement generics within my library using the [num crate `Float` trait](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/trait.Float.html), but I'm stuck fighting the compiler. This works:

```
struct Vector<T> {
    data: Vec<T>,
}

trait Metric<T> {
    fn norm(&self) -> T;
}

impl Metric<f32> for Vector<f32> {
    fn norm(&self) -> f32 {
        let mut s = 0.0;

        for u in &self.data {
            s = s + u * u;
        }

        s.sqrt()
    }
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
use num::Float; // 0.2.0

struct Vector<T> {
    data: Vec<T>,
}

trait Metric<T> {
    fn norm(&self) -> T;
}

impl<T: Float> Metric<T> for Vector<T> {
    fn norm(&self) -> T {
        let mut s = T::zero();

        for u in &self.data {
            s = s + u * u;
        }

        s.sqrt()
    }
}
```

The latter gives me the following error:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `*` cannot be applied to type `&T`
  --> src/lib.rs:16:23
   |
16 |             s = s + u * u;
   |                     - ^ - &T
   |                     |
   |                     &T
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Mul` might be missing for `&T`
```

If I remove the reference and iterate over `self.data` instead, I get a

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/lib.rs:15:18
   |
15 |         for u in self.data {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's look closer at the [`Float`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/trait.Float.html) trait. It is defined as:

```
pub trait Float: NumCast + Num + Copy + Neg<Output = Self> + PartialOrd<Self> {
    // ...
}
```

Diving into the [`Num`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/trait.Num.html) trait, we see:

```
pub trait Num: Zero + One + NumOps<Self, Self> + PartialEq<Self> {
    // ...
}
```

And deeper into [`NumOps`](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.5/num_traits/trait.NumOps.html)

```
pub trait NumOps<Rhs = Self, Output = Self>:
    Add<Rhs, Output = Output>
    + Sub<Rhs, Output = Output>
    + Mul<Rhs, Output = Output>
    + Div<Rhs, Output = Output>
    + Rem<Rhs, Output = Output>
{
    // ...
}
```

That means that any type that implements `Float` is able to be multiplied by its *own* type. Now let's turn back to your code. You are iterating over a `Vec<T>`, which gives you a *reference* to each item, a `&T`.

You have a `&T` and are trying to multiply that by another `&T`. Here's a simplified example of that:

```
fn do_a_thing<T>(a: &T, b: &T)
where
    T: Float,
{
    let z = a * b;
}
```

This gives the same error: `` binary operation `*` cannot be applied to type `&T` ``.

The problem is that you **only** know that you can multiply a `T` by another `T`. To say that, you have to explicitly dereference the variables. Since `Float` also requires `Copy`, this will work:

```
let z = (*a) * (*b);
```

Applying the same change to your original code causes it to work:

```
for u in &self.data {
    s = s + (*u) * (*u);
}
```

You can also dereference the iterator variable when pattern matching:

```
for &u in &self.data {
    s = s + u * u;
}
```

Or you can add another bound that requires that references to your type can be multiplied:

```
impl<T> Metric<T> for Vector<T>
where
    T: Float,
    for<'a> &'a T: std::ops::Mul<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    fn norm(&self) -> T {
        let mut s = T::zero();

        for u in &self.data {
            s = s + u * u;
        }

        s.sqrt()
    }
}
```

You can also add in a bound for [`AddAssign`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html) and write simpler code in the body:

```
impl<T> Metric<T> for Vector<T>
where
    T: Float + std::ops::AddAssign,
    for<'a> &'a T: std::ops::Mul<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    fn norm(&self) -> T {
        let mut s = T::zero();

        for u in &self.data {
            s += u * u;
        }

        s.sqrt()
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How to write a trait bound for adding two references of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34630695/155423)
- [How do I write the lifetimes for references in a type constraint when one of them is a local reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343166/155423)
- [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/155423)

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up - it's really helpful to see why this is the case. As for the += part am I correct in assuming that it is just not possible to use this operator for generics?

Comment: @user124784 [not yet](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html), but it's coming. [Specifying good semantics](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/953) for that operator is tougher than you'd expect :-)

Comment: I can wait :). Just to check though - the compiler's optimization will not see any difference between these?