# Rust generic AddAssign with references

Tags: rust, traits

A while ago I looked into writing a generic iterator for the Fibonacci sequence
that could accept both primitive numbers as well as custom types (such as
`bignums`). After failing to get a version working for both the primitive types
and `bignums`, I stumbled upon this question:

[How to write a trait bound for adding two references of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630695/how-to-write-a-trait-bound-for-adding-two-references-of-a-generic-type)

Which used so called *Higher Ranked Trait Bounds* to solve the problem with this
particular issue.

Now however, I'm trying to use a similar strategy to use the `*_assign`
operators instead. In particular, I'm trying to get something similar to this
working:

```
use std::ops::{Add, AddAssign};

fn add_test<'a, T>(x: &'a T, y: &'a T) -> T
where
    for<'b> &'b T: Add<Output = T>,
{
    x + y
}

fn add_assign_test<'a, T>(x: &'a mut T, y: &'a T) -> T
where
    for<'b> &'b mut T: AddAssign<&'b T>,
    T: Clone,
{
    x += y;
    x.clone()
}

fn main() {
    println!("add_test()={}", add_test(&1, &2));
    println!("add_assign_test()={}", add_assign_test(&mut 2, &2));
}
```

`add_test()` works as expected but I'm unable to get `add_assign_test()` to work in a similar way. The errors I'm getting suggest that there might not actually exist an implementation for this kind of behaviour on the primitive types:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'b> &'b mut _: std::ops::AddAssign<&'b _>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:21:38
   |
21 |     println!("add_assign_test()={}", add_assign_test(&mut 2, &2));
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `&'b mut _ += &'b _`
   |
   = help: the trait `for<'b> std::ops::AddAssign<&'b _>` is not implemented for `&'b mut _`
   = note: required by `add_assign_test`
```

I could create a macro that creates implementations for these operators that actually takes references to the primitive types, but that seems a little wasteful. Is there any other way to achieve the same effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a tiny oversight in your code. Let's look at the trait:

```
pub trait AddAssign<Rhs = Self> {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: Rhs);
}
```

The receiver of the method is already `&mut self` and not `self`. The reason that you had to do the extra work with `Add` is because it accepts `self` as receiver. For `AddAssign` this means: if a type `T` implements `AddAssign`, you can call the method `add_assign()` on a `&mut T`!

Thus, instead of writing:

```
where for <'b> &'b mut T: AddAssign<&'b T>,
```

... you would write:

```
where for <'b> T: AddAssign<&'b T>,
```

(No other line changed so far)

---

However, you notice that the code [still won't compile](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ac6f0f9c0ebfe6f02d8942706c4ec100&version=stable):

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `for<'b> {integer}: std::ops::AddAssign<&'b {integer}>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:13:38
   |
13 |     println!("add_assign_test()={}", add_assign_test(&mut 2, &2));
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `{integer} += &'b {integer}`
   |
   = help: the trait `for<'b> std::ops::AddAssign<&'b {integer}>` is not implemented for `{integer}`
   = note: required by `add_assign_test`
```

The reason is simple: there is simply no implementation of `AddAssign` for primitive types which takes an immutable reference as rhs ([Docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.AddAssign.html)). I don't know if this is an oversight -- it could be worth opening an issue on the Rust repo.

To verify the above code works, I write my own type and implemented `AddAssign` appropriately: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=456f5544179da469cf1413680b1b468a&version=stable).

Comment: Hmm, that was pretty much what I didn't want to hear :(

Looking at the rust repo tickets, I guess this is the same issue as: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32094 right?

Comment: Looking over the https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/11/22/Rust-1.22.html changes, it seems like this have actually been fixed now. Just a minor thing I noticed when revisiting this: Why do I need to dereference the left hand side `x`?

Answer (score 1):

Corrected the code snippet based on Lukas' reply:

```
use std::ops::{Add, AddAssign};

fn add_test<'a, T>(x: &'a T, y: &'a T) -> T
where
    for<'b> &'b T: Add<Output = T>,
{
    x + y
}

fn add_assign_test<'a, T>(x: &'a mut T, y: &'a T) -> T
where
    for<'b> T: AddAssign<&'b T>,
    T: Clone,
{
    *x += y;
    x.clone()
}

fn main() {
    println!("add_test()={}", add_test(&1, &2));
    println!("add_assign_test()={}", add_assign_test(&mut 2, &2));
}
```

It appears that this is an issue in Rust itself. There is currently a tracker [for this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/32094).

Until this is fixed, there's two possible workarounds:

1. Create named-tuples for each primitives and implement `OpAssign` for those types instead. This does however force you to 'cast' all primitives to your custom type.
2. Duplicate the 'generic' code with specializations for the primitives.