# How to compute arithmetic operations on a borrowed vector of elements that lack Copy in Rust?

Tags: rust

What's the proper approach to compute arithmetic operations on a borrowed vector of elements that lack `Copy` in Rust?  In the following code, I'd like `foo` to borrow a vector `x` and then compute a short function.  The trick is that the elements in `x` necessarily lack the `Copy` trait.  Anyway, the code

```rust
fn foo<Real>(x: &Vec<Real>) -> Real
where
    Real: std::ops::Add<Output = Real> + std::ops::Mul<Output = Real> + Clone,
{
    (x[0] + x[1]) * x[2]
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec![1.2, 2.3, 3.4];
    let _y = foo::<f64>(&x);
}
```

Fails to compile with the error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<Real>`
 --> src/main.rs:5:6
  |
5 |     (x[0] + x[1]) * x[2]
  |      ^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Real`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<Real>`
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
5 |     (x[0] + x[1]) * x[2]
  |             ^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Real`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `std::vec::Vec<Real>`
 --> src/main.rs:5:21
  |
5 |     (x[0] + x[1]) * x[2]
  |                     ^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Real`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

This makes sense.  The indexing attempts to move out borrowed content.  That said, if we try to borrow on the indices:

```rust
fn foo<Real>(x: &Vec<Real>) -> Real
where
    Real: std::ops::Add<Output = Real> + std::ops::Mul<Output = Real> + Clone,
{
    (&x[0] + &x[1]) * &x[2]
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec![1.2, 2.3, 3.4];
    let _y = foo::<f64>(&x);
}
```

Then, we get a new compiler error:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `+` cannot be applied to type `&Real`
 --> src/main.rs:5:12
  |
5 |     (&x[0] + &x[1]) * &x[2]
  |      ----- ^ ----- &Real
  |      |
  |      &Real
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Add` might be missing for `&Real`
```

This also makes sense; the traits `Add` and `Mul` are on `Real` and not `&Real`.  Nevertheless, I'm not sure how to resolve the error.  Is there a straightforward fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a trait bound for adding two references of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630695/how-to-write-a-trait-bound-for-adding-two-references-of-a-generic-type)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to use arcane magic call ["Higher-ranked trait bounds"](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/trait-bounds.html#higher-ranked-trait-bounds), once you learn this power you just have to use it:

```rust
fn foo<Real>(x: &[Real]) -> Real
where
    for<'a> &'a Real: std::ops::Add<Output = Real> + std::ops::Mul<Output = Real>,
{
    &(&x[0] + &x[1]) * &x[2]
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec![1.2, 2.3, 3.4];
    let _y = foo::<f64>(&x);
}
```

As you can't see we just have to ask the `&Read` implement `Add` and `Mul` but we need some sort of generic lifetime so we use `for<'a>` notation.

See:

- [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-to-a-string-string-vec-vec-o)

Answer (score 1):

If you only require `Real` to implement `Add` then you'll have to consume both `Real`s to add them. You'll need to require `Add` for `&Real` if you want to add without consuming.

Alternatively, you've added the trait bound `Clone` for `Real`, which means you can clone the `Real`s before adding them.

```
use std::ops::{Add, Mul};

// You shouldn't ever use the type &Vec<T> as an input,
// since it's unnecessarily restrictive and introduces two layers of indirection
fn foo_clone<Real>(x: &[Real]) -> Real
where
    Real: Add<Output = Real> + Mul<Output = Real> + Clone,
{
    (x[0].clone() + x[1].clone()) * x[2].clone()
}

// This uses the higher-ranked trait bounds that Stargateur mentioned
// It basically means that the implementation of `Add` for `Real`
// can't restrict the lifetime.
fn foo_ref_add<Real>(x: &[Real]) -> Real
where
    for <'a> &'a Real: Add<Output = Real> + Mul<Output = Real>,
{
    &(&x[0] + &x[1]) * &x[2]
}

fn main() {
    let x = vec![1.2, 2.3, 3.4];
    let _y = foo_clone::<f64>(&x);
    let _z = foo_ref_add::<f64>(&x);
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3a9538410455c60bbc147f69cc6d76e7)