# Rust how to add two referenced i32's together?

Tags: rust

```rust
fn main() {
    
    fn calculate_two_numbers<T:Debug, const N: usize>(data_set: [T;N]) -> (i32,i32) {
        
        // Key Code 
        let a = &data_set[0]+&data_set[1];
        println!("{:?},{:?},{:?}",&data_set[0],&data_set[1],a);
        
        // Ignore
        return (0,0)
    }

let data = [1509,1857,1736,1815,1576];
let result = calculate_two_numbers(data);
}
```

I have a very simple function which takes a list of size n.

From this list, I want to take the first two variables and add them together. I then want to print all of them out with println!.

However, I get the error `error[E0369]: cannot add &T to &T`

This is the solution the complier suggests but I have trouble understanding it

```
fn calculate_two_numbers<T:Debug + std::ops::Add<Output = &T>, const N: usize>(data_set: [T;N])
```

Can someone explain what `std::ops::Add<Output = &T>` does?

Comment: First of all just use `data_set[0]+data_set[1]`. `Add` is a trait. You say that `T` has this trait, that is `T` has an operation `T + T` that in turn produces `T` value

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630695/how-to-write-a-trait-bound-for-adding-two-references-of-a-generic-type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rust, when using generic types, you need to tell the compiler what kind of operations you would want to do with the type. This is done be constraining the bounds of your type (You are already using it with `Debug`, it means you can use it as it were a debug type).

The compiler suggest to add the `Add` trait, but it will not really work straight away because of the references. You can either add a **lifetime** or use `Copy` (with would be probably desirable if you are gonna work with numbers), again add it as another bound:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::ops::Add;

fn calculate_two_numbers<T: Debug + Add::<Output=T> + Copy, const N: usize>(data_set: [T; N]) -> (i32, i32) {
    // Key Code
    let a = data_set[0] + data_set[1];
    println!("{:?},{:?},{:?}", data_set[0], data_set[1], a);

    // Ignore
    return (0, 0);
}

fn main() {
    let data = [1509, 1857, 1736, 1815, 1576];
    let result = calculate_two_numbers(data);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c953eb675c6e274fa2411db5b4855882)

If using the references approach, you need to specify that for any lifetime for your references that reference implements `Add<Output=T>`:

```rust
fn calculate_two_numbers<T: Debug, const N: usize>(data_set: [T; N]) -> (i32, i32)
where
    for<'a> &'a T: Add<Output = T>,
{
    // Key Code
    let a = &data_set[0] + &data_set[1];
    println!("{:?},{:?},{:?}", data_set[0], data_set[1], a);

    // Ignore
    return (0, 0);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fbe740a222ff4cefe0541b281506f321)