# How do I write the lifetimes for references in a type constraint when one of them is a local reference?

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime

I have a trait `Matrix` and generic function `semi_def<T: Matrix>(x: &T)` that I would like to operate on that trait. The function requires an operator trait, say `Mul`, be implemented on `T`. However, I can't seem to make the lifetimes happy if one of the references is to a local variable. How do I write the lifetimes for references in the type constraint when one of them is just a local temporary reference?

```
use std::ops::Mul;

trait Matrix: Clone {
    fn transpose(self) -> Self;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct DenseMatrix {
    n_rows: usize,
    n_columns: usize,
    elements: Vec<f64>,
}

impl Matrix for DenseMatrix {
    fn transpose(self) -> Self {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl<'a, 'b> Mul<&'b DenseMatrix> for &'a DenseMatrix {
    type Output = DenseMatrix;
    fn mul(self, _rhs: &'b DenseMatrix) -> Self::Output {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn semi_def<'a, T: Matrix>(x: &'a T) -> T
where
    &'a T: Mul<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    &(*x).clone().transpose() * x
}

fn main() {}
```

which gives this error:

```
error[E0597]: borrowed value does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:31:6
   |
31 |     &(*x).clone().transpose() * x
   |      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ temporary value does not live long enough
32 | }
   | - temporary value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 27:1...
  --> src/main.rs:27:1
   |
27 | / fn semi_def<'a, T: Matrix>(x: &'a T) -> T
28 | | where
29 | |     &'a T: Mul<&'a T, Output = T>,
30 | | {
31 | |     &(*x).clone().transpose() * x
32 | | }
   | |_^
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need higher-ranked trait bounds (HRTBs), which [are described in the advanced Rust book Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) and well as [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592750/how-does-for-syntax-differ-from-a-regular-lifetime-bound). They allow a type constraint to say that trait must be implemented not just for references with a particular lifetime but for any lifetime. They use the `where for<>` syntax. Here is the function definition that says an implementation of `Mul` is needed for any two references to `T`:

```
fn semi_def<'a, T: Matrix>(x: &'a T) -> T
where
    for<'b, 'c> &'b T: Mul<&'c T, Output = T>,
{
    &(*x).clone().transpose() * x
}
```

Because one of the references actually has the lifetime `'a`, not a local lifetime, this could be written with a slightly looser constraint:

```
fn semi_def<'a, T: Matrix>(x: &'a T) -> T
where
    for<'b> &'b T: Mul<&'a T, Output = T>,
{
    &(*x).clone().transpose() * x
}
```

<sub>This Q&A is based off [a question](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/lifetimes-for-type-constraint-where-one-reference-is-local/11087) I asked on the Rust users mailing, which I cleaned up and brought over here for future Rustaceans.</sub>

Comment: Why `&(*x)` ? You are taking a reference of the cloned, transposed "x" and then multiplying it?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant In the question, `Mul` is only defined for `&'a DenseMatrix`, so the input must be a reference. Note that because of associativity, it is more clearly written `&((*x).clone().transpose())`