# Borrowed value does not live long enough when iterating over a generic value with a lifetime on the function body

Tags: rust, lifetime

```
fn func<'a, T>(arg: Vec<Box<T>>)
where
    String: From<&'a T>,
    T: 'a,
{
    let s: Vec<String> = arg.iter().map(|s| String::from(s)).collect();
    do_something_else(arg);
}

fn do_something_else<T>(arg: Vec<Box<T>>) {}
```

The compiler complains that `arg` does not live long enough. Why though?

```
error[E0597]: `arg` does not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:6:26
  |
6 |     let s: Vec<String> = arg.iter().map(|s| String::from(s)).collect();
  |                          ^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
7 |     do_something_else(arg);
8 | }
  | - borrowed value only lives until here
  |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the function body at 1:9...
 --> src/lib.rs:1:9
  |
1 | fn func<'a, T>(arg: Vec<Box<T>>)
  |         ^^
```

Comment: So you want to use `arg` after collecting the members into `s`? Else I would say use `into_iter` and it's all done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constraint `String: From<&'a T>`, with emphasis on the function's lifetime parameter `'a`, would allow you to convert a reference to `T` to a `String`. However, the reference to the elements obtained from the iterator *is more restrictive* than `'a` (hence, they do not live long enough).

Since the conversion is supposed to work fine for references of any lifetime, you may replace the constraint with a higher ranked trait bound (HRTB):

```
fn func<T>(arg: Vec<Box<T>>)
where
    for<'a> String: From<&'a T>,
{
    let s: Vec<String> = arg.iter().map(|s| String::from(s)).collect();
    do_something_else(arg);
}
```

The use of `From` here to obtain an owned string is also not something I've seen in the wild. Perhaps you would be interested in the `Display` trait, so that you can call `to_string()`:

```
fn func<T>(arg: Vec<Box<T>>)
where
    T: Display,
{
    let _: Vec<_> = arg.iter().map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
    // ...
}
```

See also:

- [How do I write the lifetimes for references in a type constraint when one of them is a local reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343166/155423)
- [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/155423)