# "borrowed value does not live long enough", but why do we need it to live so long?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

There are lots of similar questions, but I couldn't find the answer to my exact question.

In my Rust code, I have a generic type and want to implement a method that takes a reference to another instance of the that type, and then another method that consumes its argument but does exactly the same thing as the first one:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct Wrapper<T> {
    v: T,
}

impl<T> Wrapper<T> {
    pub fn f_ref(&self, _other: &Wrapper<T>) { /* ... */ }
    pub fn f_consume(&self, other: Wrapper<T>) {
        self.f_ref(&other)
    }
}
```

It compiles just fine.

Now I want to do basically the same, but while implementing a trait. First, the function that takes a reference:

```
use std::ops::AddAssign;

impl<'a, T> AddAssign<&'a Wrapper<T>> for Wrapper<T> where T: AddAssign<&'a T> {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, other: &'a Wrapper<T>) {
        self.v += &other.v;
    }
}

#[test]
fn test() {
    let mut a = Wrapper { v: 1_i32 };
    let b = Wrapper { v: 2 };
    a += &b;
    drop(b);
    assert_eq!(a, Wrapper { v: 3 });
}
```

It works, too.

Now I want to implement `AddAssign` for `Wrapper<T>` based on the implementation of `AddAssign<&Wrapper<T>>` that I already have. I understand that if `T` has references in it, it will cause trouble, so I **make sure it has `'static` lifetime**. I'm OK with it: in my program, I expect `T` to be something like an owned matrix of numbers wrapped in some custom struct.

```
impl<'a, T> AddAssign for Wrapper<T> where T: 'static + AddAssign<&'a T>, Wrapper<T>: 'static {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, other: Wrapper<T>) {
        *self += &other;
    }
}
```

And it fails. The compiler says that `other` must stay valid after we used a reference to it to in a `+=` expression. But when we used such a reference in the `test()` function above and dropped `b` there (which played the role of `other` here) and used the result later, the compiler agreed it's OK. Why?

I suspect that I need to specify some additional trait bounds for `T` or `Wrapper<T>` but don't understand what these bound should be.

[Code in playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9a8ecfa68f39543822b9e84d0df0a2e)

Comment: To apply the duplicate here: use either `where T: for<'a> AddAssign<&'a T>` or `where Wrapper<T>: for<'a> AddAssign<&'a Wrapper<T>>` (what I would write). [Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e37a241f43aaa5b9f3b7c75f39015a34)

Comment: [Borrowed value does not live long enough when iterating over a generic value with a lifetime on the function body](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53485574/3650362) has the same error for the same reason. [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/3650362) is another related question.

Comment: Oh my rusty god. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! You're not wrong that there are lots of similar questions, but HRTBs are a thing that don't make much sense until you find you need them, and hard to search for unless you already know what they are. Hopefully marking this question as a duplicate will help others find the same answers.