# Lifetime parameters in supertrait bounds

Tags: rust, traits, lifetime

I'm trying to define a trait for an object that is convertible to and from a slice of bytes. I essentially want to say

```
trait Foo: AsRef<[u8]> + TryFrom<&[u8]> {}
```

Unfortunately, this refuses to compile unless I put a lifetime parameter on the reference, like so:

```
trait Foo<'a>: AsRef<[u8]> + TryFrom<&'a [u8]> {}
```

This doesn't make much sense to me, because the lifetime `'a` is related to the eventual `try_from()` call and shouldn't have to be part of the object's type. (The implementation of `try_from()` copies the relevant bytes, so the lifetime of its parameter really isn't relevant.)

This seems like a more general issue than just slices, though; how do you specify lifetime parameters like this for supertrait bounds? (Apparently `'_` doesn't work.) And is there a better/more idiomatic way to express this, or do I have to resort to some sort of hand-rolled custom nonsense like

```
pub trait TryFromRef<T> { type Error; fn try_from(value: &T) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>; }
```

?

Comment: There must be a duplicate for this one, I'll look for it. The answer is to use a *higher-ranked trait bound*: `trait Foo: AsRef<[u8]> + for<'a> TryFrom<&'a [u8]> {}`

Comment: @trentcl Genius. I remember reading about those in the Book, but didn't connect it with this issue. Stick it in an answer and I'll accept

Comment: Yeah, the other questions I was thinking of aren't exactly what you're looking for IMO. I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trait bound with a lifetime parameter that holds for all lifetimes, rather than for some particular lifetime, can be specified with a so-called *higher-ranked trait bound*, or HRTB. In your case this might look like

```
trait Foo: AsRef<[u8]> + for<'a> TryFrom<&'a [u8]> {}
```

Anything implementing `Foo` must satisfy `TryFrom<&'a u8>` for any and all choices of `'a`, so there's no need for a lifetime on `Foo` itself.

### See also

- [How do I write the lifetimes for references in a type constraint when one of them is a local reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343166/3650362)
- [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/3650362)