# Unexpected error when using explicit lifetime in template argument in Rust

Tags: rust, lifetime

Consider the (admittedly contrived) rust program below where there's a function `toto` that takes no arguments except for a template argument `T`:

```rust
use std::fmt::Debug;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct X;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Y;

impl<'a> From<&'a X> for Y {
    fn from(_x: &'a X) -> Self { Self }
}

fn toto<'a,T>()
where T: From<&'a X> + Debug {
    let x = X;
    let y = T::from(&x);
    println!("{:?}",y);
    println!("{:?}",x);
}

fn main() {
    toto::<Y>();
}
```

I expected `toto` to desugar something like this (which I believe is valid):

```rust
'b {
    let x = X;
    'a {
        let y = T::from(&x);
        println!("{:?}",y); // last use of y
    }
    println!("{:?}",x); // last use of x
}
```

Instead I get this error:

```
error[E0597]: `x` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:16:19
   |
13 | fn toto<'a,T>()
   |         -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
16 |   let y = T::from(&x);
   |           --------^^-
   |           |       |
   |           |       borrowed value does not live long enough
   |           argument requires that `x` is borrowed for `'a`
...
19 | }
   | - `x` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Why does the compiler think the `'a` lasts longer than `'b` instead of `'a` being contained in `'b` like in the desugared version above? Can I have `'a` live only in the body of the function so that the code desugars as I had expected?

Comment: Is the first line of `toto` supposed to be `let x = ...`, rather than `let Y = ...`? I'm getting "`x` not found" when I try to compile this.

Comment: You have two different lifetimes named `'a`: one is the lifetime parameter on the function, one is the name of the scope inside `'b`. The compiler is telling you that `x` does not outlive the function parameter `'a` and you're asking why doesn't it outlive the scope `'a`. If you [rename the inner one to `'c`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=195953ba38649dc6bcd0c824cd7ae01c) it should be more obvious what the compiler is complaining about: `x` will be dropped at the end of the function, so it can't live for `'a`, which is chosen by the caller.

Comment: It looks like you need an [HRTB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343166/3650362). Applied to your scenario that would look like ``fn toto<T>() where T: for<'a> From<&'a X> + Debug { ... }``

Comment: Don't know how I missed `let Y = ...`, but now it's fixed @SCappella.

Comment: That worked @trentcl. Thanks for clearing that up for me. Does that make this question a duplicate?

Comment: @user35690 Yeah, I suppose so. But I can't flag it (already voted on the question and retracted it when you fixed the error in the code). You should be able to dupe-flag it yourself, I think.