# How to write a macro that splits a byte into a tuple of bits of user-specified count?

Tags: rust, macros, rust-macros

I would like to have macro splitting one byte into tuple with 2-8 u8 parts using `bitreader` crate.

I managed to achieve that by following code:

```rust
use bitreader::BitReader;

trait Tupleprepend<T> {
    type ResultType;
    fn prepend(self, t: T) -> Self::ResultType;
}

macro_rules! impl_tuple_prepend {
    ( () ) => {};
    ( ( $t0:ident $(, $types:ident)* ) ) => {
        impl<$t0, $($types,)* T> Tupleprepend<T> for ($t0, $($types,)*) {
            type ResultType = (T, $t0, $($types,)*);

            fn prepend(self, t: T) -> Self::ResultType {
                let ($t0, $($types,)*) = self;
                (t, $t0, $($types,)*)
            }
        }

        impl_tuple_prepend! { ($($types),*) }
    };
}

impl_tuple_prepend! {
    (_1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6, _7, _8)
}

macro_rules! split_byte (
    ($reader:ident, $bytes:expr, $count:expr) => {{
        ($reader.read_u8($count).unwrap(),)
    }};
    ($reader:ident, $bytes:expr, $count:expr, $($next_counts:expr),+) => {{
        let head = split_byte!($reader, $bytes, $count);
        let tail = split_byte!($reader, $bytes, $($next_counts),+);
        tail.prepend(head.0)
    }};
    ($bytes:expr $(, $count:expr)* ) => {{
        let mut reader = BitReader::new($bytes);
        split_byte!(reader, $bytes $(, $count)+)
    }};
);
```

Now I can use this code as I would like to:

```rust
let buf: &[u8] = &[0x72];
let (bit1, bit2, bits3to8) = split_byte!(&buf, 1, 1, 6);
```

Is there a way to avoid using `Tupleprepend` trait and create only 1 tuple instead of 8 in the worst scenario?

Comment: Why use a macro at the call site at all? Use _only_ a trait and you can do `let (b1, b2, b3_8) = 0x72.split_byte()`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not made myself clear enough. I would like to have possibility to split a vector in every possible combination. So  i.e. `split_byte!(&[0x72], 3, 2)` would give me a two element tuple created out of first 3 and next 2 bytes.

Comment: That *slice* (there is no vector here) only has a single value in it. What type is the number? `u8`? `i128`?

Comment: It is `u8` type.

Comment: If it's a `u8` then there's _only_ one byte to start with, so you _can't_ get the "first 3" or "next 2" bytes.

Comment: I ment bits of course.

Answer (score 0):

Because the number of bit widths directly corresponds to the number of returned values, I'd solve the problem using generics and arrays instead. The macro only exists to remove the typing of the `[]`, which I don't really think is worth it.

```rust
fn split_byte<A>(b: u8, bit_widths: A) -> A
where
    A: Default + std::ops::IndexMut<usize, Output = u8>,
    for<'a> &'a A: IntoIterator<Item = &'a u8>,
{
    let mut result = A::default();
    let mut start = 0;
    for (idx, &width) in bit_widths.into_iter().enumerate() {
        let shifted = b >> (8 - width - start);
        let mask = (0..width).fold(0, |a, _| (a << 1) | 1);
        result[idx] = shifted & mask;
        start += width;
    }
    result
}

macro_rules! split_byte {
    ($b:expr, $($w:expr),+) => (split_byte($b, [$($w),+]));
}

fn main() {
    let [bit1, bit2, bits3_to_8] = split_byte!(0b1010_1010, 1, 1, 6);
    assert_eq!(bit1, 0b1);
    assert_eq!(bit2, 0b0);
    assert_eq!(bits3_to_8, 0b10_1010);
}
```

See also:

- [How does for<> syntax differ from a regular lifetime bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35592750/155423)
- [How to write a trait bound for adding two references of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34630695/155423)
- [How do I write the lifetimes for references in a type constraint when one of them is a local reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44343166/155423)

If it's ok to target nightly Rust, I'd use the unstable `min_const_generics` feature:

```rust
#![feature(min_const_generics)]

fn split_byte<const N: usize>(b: u8, bit_widths: [u8; N]) -> [u8; N] {
    let mut result = [0; N];
    let mut start = 0;
    for (idx, &width) in bit_widths.iter().enumerate() {
        let shifted = b >> (8 - width - start);
        let mask = (0..width).fold(0, |a, _| (a << 1) | 1);
        result[idx] = shifted & mask;
        start += width;
    }
    result
}

macro_rules! split_byte {
    ($b:expr, $($w:expr),+) => (split_byte($b, [$($w),+]));
}

fn main() {
    let [bit1, bit2, bits3_to_8] = split_byte!(0b1010_1010, 1, 1, 6);
    assert_eq!(bit1, 0b1);
    assert_eq!(bit2, 0b0);
    assert_eq!(bits3_to_8, 0b10_1010);
}
```

See also:

- [Is it possible to control the size of an array using the type parameter of a generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28136739/155423)